# Proving limits of the composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

My question reads:

Let $z$ be a limit point of $X$, and $y$ a limit point of $Y$. Suppose that $f:X\to Y\hspace{.1cm}\backslash\hspace{.1cm}\big\{y\big\}$ and $g:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions such that $\lim_{x \to z} f(x) = y$, and $\lim_{x \to y} g(x) = L$. Show that $\lim_{x \to z} (g\circ f)(x) = L$.

Proof:

Taking the compostion of $f,g$, we have that $(g\circ f):X\to\mathbb{R}$.

Let, ($x_n$)$\subseteq X$ such that ($x_n)\to z$ and $x_n\neq z$.

Now, let $(y_n)=f(x_n)$. Also, by the sequential criterion of the limit of f, we have that $f(x_n)\to y$.

Then, by the sequential criterion of the limit of $g$, it follows that $g(f(x_n))\to L$.

Does this make sense or should I fix my proof after taking the composition?

Comment: I think the third paragraph is a little strange, it seems that you have assumed the continuity of $f\circ g$ in order to use the sequential criterion. Indeed you cannot assume that because that is what you gonna prove. Meanwhile, since you are dealing with $x\rightarrow z$ with $f\circ g(x)$, it's better to directly write that let $x_{n}\rightarrow z$ and $x\ne z$ at the very beginning of your proof.

Comment: I think now you should start the argument from the fourth paragraph (let $(x_{n})\subseteq X...$), the first, second, and third paragraph, to me, are just monologue how's the proof should built, in practice, they need not to be present.

Comment: @user284331 I see, I think I just wanted to include that other stuff so it helps with the proof later on. Although, yes it could be cut down.

Comment: The sentence "By the sequential criterion, it follows that $(g\circ f)(x_{n})\rightarrow d$" is misleading. Which sequential criterion? Actually this sentence is no needed. And the fifth paragraph you should note that by the sequential criterion of the limit of $g$ at $y$, it follows that $g(f(x_{n}))\rightarrow L$.

Comment: Sorry that's typo, it should be limit instead of continuity.

Comment: Now perhaps you should add one more thing to clarify that... it follows that $g(f(x_{n}))\rightarrow L$, so $(g\circ f)(x_{n})\rightarrow L$. And as I have said, those "monologue" statements are not needed in actual proof.

Comment: Now your proof goes through.

Comment: That is not needed.

Comment: why bother with sequences when a standard $\epsilon-\delta$ argument is easier, (and more general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is perhaps a slightly clearer way of stating your argument, which I think looks mostly correct.

Fix an arbitrary sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset X$ such that $x_n \to z$, with $x_n \neq z$ for each $n$. Define the sequence $\{ y_n \}$ by $y_n = f(x_n)$. It is easy to see that $y_n \to y$.

Since $y_n \to y$, we also have that $g(y_n) \to L$. In other words, $g(f(x_n)) \to L$. Since the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ was arbitrary, we have that

$$ \lim_{x \to z} (f \circ g)(x) = L. $$

Comment: It could be a change you make towards the end, but I suppose you could also think of this as making explicit the argument you make in the last line, so it could come right after as well.

Comment: I just updated my proof. By writing this before, do you mean instead of mentioning the sequential criterion, we could mention it after taking an arbitrary sequence in $X$?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. I've read your updated proof. The third paragraph is a little confusing. It seems you're asserting what it is you're trying to prove, without actually having shown it yet (which you do in the last paragraph, albeit somewhat unclearly, though this may be a matter of personal taste).

Comment: Also, how do we know that $y_n$ $\to y$ in this case?

Comment: Here the $y_{n}$ is just $f(x_{n})$, and $f(x_{n})\rightarrow y$ just because of the limit of $f$ at $z$

Comment: Right, I noticed this when rereading what I had to work with.

Comment: Okay, I made all these changes now and I think it is now fine.

Comment: Then, the proof just ends up being quite short right?

Comment: @Pam_22R yes, it looks fine now.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Just one more thing, instead of saying the limit of $f$ at $z$ can I say since $\lim_{x \to z} f(x) = y$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist So, where I have in my proof "by the sequential criterion of the limit of $f$, can I say instead by $\lim_{x \to z} f(x) = y$? Also, the same thing thing for when I mention the sequential criterion for $g$, can I say by $\lim_{x \to y} g(x) = L$

Comment: @Pam_22R if I understood you correctly, then, yes. In fact I think writing it that way is clearer. Perhaps you can edit your question and I can tell you if it reads better?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist okay yes, I will edit my post just to make sure it makes sense.

Comment: @Pam_22R yes, the edit looks good.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist okay thank you. I just can’t belive the proof is actually quite short. I see I did not need all the other information I had before.

Comment: @Pam_22R Good proofs of simple results tend to be quite short. If you notice, now your proof very closely resembles the one I proposed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not take into account earlier that $(y_{n})$ in the sequential criterion of $g$. Rather, instantiate the sequential criterion to $(f(x_{n}))$ which the element is none of $y$ by the assumption. Then the rest goes through.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I understand what you mean by instantiate the sequential criterion to ($f(x_n$))? Do you mean use what we know about $g$?

Comment: In other words, take $(y_{n})=(f(x_{n}))$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by the last line in my question. But then do I not need to restate the sequential criterion for $(g\circ f$)?

Comment: More so, why can I just take $(y_{n})=(f(x_{n}))$?

Comment: I got you. In fact, you should start writing that let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $X$, $x_{n}\ne z$, and $x_{n}\rightarrow z$.

Comment: Do you mean $z$? For which part of the proof are you referring to?

Comment: Because you really found a sequence $(f(x_{n}))$ in $Y$ which converges to $y$ and $f(x_{n})\ne y$. So such a sequence $(f(x_{n}))$ really satisfies the candidate to be $(y_{n})$ of the sequential criterion of $g$ at $y$.

Comment: Okay, I sort of understand what you mean. I just do not see how what I really found was a sequence in Y, aren't we in X?

Comment: The codomain of function $f$ is $Y$ (except for $y$), so the values $f(x_{n})$ really values in $Y$. So it forms a sequence in $Y$.

Comment: OH, wow oops, totally missed that point. Wow, thank you. Let me see if I can update my proof and see that it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I made changes. Does this read better?